# How do I reposition a UITableViewCell's contentView to the left or right?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to create a "sliding" effect left and right. I know how to use gestures, but what method allows me to set where a contentView is on the left and right? Its frame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't move the `contentView` (or you shouldn't). But feel free to put a big view inside it (containing everything else in the cell) and move *that* view!

Answer (score 1):

For add a sliding effect to cell on tableview, try this: https://github.com/boctor/idev-recipes/tree/master/SideSwipeTableView

Comment: I'm referring more so to sliding the cell (like in Reeder) rather than swiping the cell.

Comment: Ok, I had misunderstood. But maybe you can use part of code for your needs.